# Высота родителя флексбока не работает процентах

Tags: flexbox

Как сделать высоту родительского блока в процентах (На самом деле мне нужно `padding-bottom` в %)

Вот что я хочу сделать, но только высоту не фиксированную, а в процентах [Демо](https://jsfiddle.net/Xahon/j1z1yjk5/)

---

**UPD**

Решил я в общем свою проблему, дав главному блоку абсолютную позицию и обернув его в другой див, который и задает размеры [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Xahon/e5r8uhzy/1/)

Comment: Уточните вопрос.  Высоту какого элемента. Добавьте код. Суть проблемы вообще не ясна

Comment: @yuri `modal_news_wrapper` у этого элемента высота нужна в %

Comment: @Herrgott, `.modal_news_wrapper {
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    padding-bottom: 40%;
}`

Comment: @elena ну так не работает

Comment: @Herrgott, что бы так работало, нужно заключить его в блок, у которого будет фиксированная высота. Тогда в процентах будет работать

Comment: @yuri  я же говорю, что фиксированная высота мне не нужна, мне нужна относительная. С фиксированной высотой я могу `calc` использовать

Comment: @Herrgott, относительную высоту нельзя указать без фиксированной высоты родителя! Или используйте js/jquery

Comment: @yuri ну что за [чушь](https://jsfiddle.net/Xahon/e5r8uhzy/)

Comment: @Herrgott, укажите ширину и высоту `body` с `html` и всё пойдёт: https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/j1z1yjk5/2/